# Delayed Filtering

Tags: javascript, html, search, dom-events

I'm trying to do a delayed filter in Javascript. Basically I have a textbox whereby the user inputs his search term.  However, I do not want to filter the data on each keypress, but rather wait 3 seconds after each keypress and then once the user stops inputting characters and these 3 seconds elapse, the filtering/search fires.

Below is my try, however the search is firing after 3 seconds each time I enter a character.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Also, is there a way to automatically grab the text inside the text field without assigning the input id/class (the idea is to use the same function for different textfields)?  If possible, i'd like to keep it plain Javascript without the need of jQuery.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search" onKeyDown="filter(3);">
```

JS:

```
function filter(secs) {

 var delay = 0;
 var delayTimeout;

 delay = secs*1000;
 clearTimeout(delayTimeout);

 delayTimeout = setTimeout(mySearchFunction, delay);

}

function mySearchFunction() {
   searchterm = document.getElementById('search').value;
   alert("Searching for: " + searchterm);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `delayTimeout` declaration out of the `filter` function:

```
var delay = 0;
var delayTimeout;

function filter(sec){
    // etc
```

Otherwise, you're resetting `delayTimeout` every time `filter()` is called, which means `clearTimeout(delayTimeout)` can't clear the timeout any more.

Comment: So, @user1809790, does this answer help you? Or do you need something else?

Comment: thanks for your answer.  This solves the main part of it :)  Now, is there a way I can get the value of the textbox passed to the search function without having to assign an ID or class on the textfield and then get the value as document.getElementById('search').value;  ?

Comment: @user1809790: Not really, no. The `id` is usually the way to go when trying to get a input's content (/value)

Comment: there's no way to use the "this" command right?  (sorry if this is silly, i'm new to this)

Comment: @user1809790: Hm, I think you could use `this.value`. No harm in trying ;-)

Comment: that returned undefined unfortunately :(